# Row Level Trigger for insert/update to a table

Tags: mysql, trigger

Given a table **ITEM** as below :

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (
ItemNo        int not null,
category      varchar(20) not null,
Quantity      int not null,
Price       decimal(10,2) not null,
Total       decimal(10,2) not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_item primary key (ItemNo)
);
```

I need to write a **row-level trigger** called **update_item** that will fire whenever **Quantity and/or Price is inserted/updated**. When this happens, the Total column will be set by the trigger as the product of Quantity and Price.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be a trigger?...a generated column would be a lot simpler and likely a more performant approach to automatically calculate the `Total` here. If such an alternative is acceptable I'll post an answer.

Comment: You shouldn't store any data that can be computed at query runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you need to make deferent trigger for updating and Inserting;

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER before_ITEM _insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON ITEM FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.Total = NEW.Quantity * NEW.Price;   
END $$

DELIMITER ;

CREATE TRIGGER before_ITEM _UPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE
ON ITEM FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.Total = NEW.Quantity * NEW.Price;   
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But for that purpose you can use generated Columns like

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM (
ItemNo        int not null,
category      varchar(20) not null,
Quantity      int not null,
Price       decimal(10,2) not null,
Total       decimal(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (Quantity * Price),
CONSTRAINT pk_item primary key (ItemNo)
);
```

Comment: Why on BEFORE INSERT ? I was thinking it will be AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT operation ? Isn't it ?

Comment: It must be BEFORE to uupdate the value of the total column, that is how tirggers work. AFTER INSERT is only for updateing other tables, else it fails

Comment: One can't write a single trigger to handle INSERT OR UPDATE operations ? Something like CREATE TRIGGER update_item BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON ITEM

Comment: no mysql has no option for that. an isert has only NEW and Update HAs NEWand OLD and a DELTE Triger has only OLD, to handle old and new values, so chekc the documentation